# How to show theme on front end before sign up for multisite

Tags: multisite

I am working on new project which based on Wordpress Multisite I have done with the wp multisite set up and site creation functionality from front end. now what I need to do is to show the theme at front end to user and user will select the theme and after the theme select user will sign up and the new site is created with the theme active which the user select. Please provide and suggestion

Comment: Can some one ans my question. You are welcome in advance.

Comment: Hi. Well yes, it can be done. You can use the hooks signup_blogform and wpmu_validate_blog_signup to add for example radio buttons on blog signup to choose from the themes. You can get the themes with wp_get_themes(). And you can show their screenshots, with the WP_Theme::get_screenshot() method.

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us your efforts.

Comment: Hello Max I am doing it in first time so I have no idea about it I was looking for some plugins but did not get any so that I am trying it by hooks can you provide me any example.

Comment: Hi Nikolay can you provide me proper code for this if possible thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I don't want to spend the time writing the whole thing.

Comment: Have you seen if this helps you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70169/allow-user-to-select-a-theme-to-install-when-they-signup

Comment: Hello  Nikolay,
I have seen this but not working can you tell me how the select theme functionality I can use i.e when user select the theme the same theme will be activate once website is created after sign-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to get the theme screen shot and theme name at front end for multi-site sign-up page.

```
$themes = wp_get_themes();
foreach( $themes as $theme ){
  echo '<b>Theme Name:  </b>' . $theme -> name;
  echo '<div class="area"><img src="' . esc_url($theme->get_screenshot()) . '" /> </div>';
}
```

Comment: Now what I need to do is I have to show the one check box by checking it when the user will sign up the new site should activate the new theme. If some one can suggest me please reply much appreciated.